# I need to run and fill Salesforce Web-to-lead form on herokuapp

Tags: html, heroku, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, heroku-cli

I generated a Web-to-lead in Salesforce form, received an html file, installed a heroku CLI and registered in heroku. What should I do next to run this form in an html file and create a new record in the Lead object in Salesforce. I need a detailed answer as a beginner.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This question does not have enough detail, but it sounds like maybe you were following a tutorial or some kind of documentation? I suggest you go back to that resource and see what _it_ tells you to do next. Heroku doesn't "run forms", and "running" HTML doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a static html page you want to upload somewhere to Heroku. Heroku doesn't do "static" stuff, you can "trick" it into treating your page as a PHP project.

Have you seen posts like

- https://medium.com/@winnieliang/how-to-run-a-simple-html-css-javascript-application-on-heroku-4e664c541b0b
- https://medium.com/@agavitalis/how-to-deploy-a-simple-static-html-website-on-heroku-492697238e48
- https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/deploy-static-site-heroku
- https://javascript.plainenglish.io/deploy-your-static-sites-for-free-on-heroku-in-seconds-7644959356a7

Or really you could follow any detailed Heroku "getting started" guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/start

Comment: I used this post: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/deploy-your-static-sites-for-free-on-heroku-in-seconds-7644959356a7 . Big thanks!